# can't convert Question into Integer error In a rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a Rails 3 application that utilizes a MySQL database there are the following integers:

```
current_user.id is an integer
Questions table - id is an integer
Answers table - question_id and user_id are integers
```

In my controller:

```
@questions.each do |q|
  ans[q] = Answer.where("question_id = ? AND user_id = ?", q.id, current_user.id ) # this is line 27
end
```

Why do I get the following error:

> can't convert Question into Integer
>
> app/controllers/applets_controller.rb:27:in `[]='
>   app/controllers/applets_controller.rb:27:in`show'
>   app/controllers/applets_controller.rb:25:in `show'

Thanks!

Comment: @theIV response to your comment edited into post above. Thanks!

Comment: @apneadiving, Thanks! People look like their dogs, right? :=]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
ans[q.id] = Answer.where("question_id = ? AND user_id = ?", q.id, current_user.id )
```

Comment: that works when i change id to position which controls the order in the array. So "q" without ".position" represents the whole array then... i get it. Thanks.